# Accessing a Storyboard ViewController from AppDelegate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am trying to access an Array variable in a view controller in an application that is using storyboards.

**BACKGROUND:**

I have been following along with the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial on Storyboards](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Once I finished the tutorial, I went back tried a different route, though I’m having trouble accessing  a view controller. Everything is pretty much the same except my set up is the initial Scene is a View Controller. I am to the part where the author is adding some data to NSMutableArray in his table.

**THEIR CODE THAT I AM USING AS A GUIDE**

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController; 
UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][0]; 
PlayersViewController *playersViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0]; 
playersViewController.players = _players;
```

I was hoping it would be a simple as replicating what I had seen with view controllers, passing along the appropriate type, but no.

I have  View Controller > View Controller > Navigation View Controller > UITableViewController.

[image: ScreenShot]

**MY CODE:**

```
UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController vc1 = [vc viewController][0]; 
UINavigationController *nc = [vc1 viewController][0];
SearchViewTableViewController *svc = [nc viewControllers][0];
svc.myarray = _myarray;
```

I have tried multiple combinations and am getting nowhere.

There has got to be a simpler way for me to reference classes/view/scenes.
Any help?

Comment: A UIViewController is not an array so this `[vc viewController][0];` or this `[vc1 viewController][0];` doesn't make sense. I don't understand what you're trying to do at all...

Comment: Note that the viewController*s* property is an array, not viewController. Though I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish by deviating from the code in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are importing the ViewController header file.
Make sure you have given you ViewController a Storyboard identifier.
Then something like this should work:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
myVC.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
....
```